# How to get the user while Logout In django

Tags: python, django, logout

I'm trying to get the user that logout from django and pass that as argyment to an external python script. 
Here is my logout view:

```
def logoutUser(request):
    user = request.user
    exec = run([sys.executable,'scriptlogout.py', user], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    logout(request)
    return redirect('beesy:Login')
```

But that dosen't work and i coudldn't retreive the user clicking on logout

Thanks for helping me

Comment: `user` is *not* a string, it is a `User` object (well strictly speaking a lazy object), so you can not use `user` in the `run` part.

Comment: thanks for your response do you have any suggestion how to do what i wann do ?

Comment: What if you use `exec = run([sys.executable,'scriptlogout.py', user.username], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well thanks everybody, i've used str() and it works very fine:

```
def logoutUser(request):
    user = str(request.user)
    exec = run([sys.executable,'scriptlogout.py', user], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    logout(request)
    return redirect('beesy:Login')
```